# How to add nofollow attribute to links in profile text field and url field

Tags: users, 6

I add 2 fields via Profile module,one is textarea field names "About me", the other one is url field names  "my website". My questions is how to add nofollow attribute to the links in these 2 fields. I googled for a while but without luck.

Answer (score 2):

In your link field settings, there is a setting...

Rel Attribute rel = " "

When output, this link will have this rel attribute. The most common usage is rel="nofollow" which prevents some search engines from spidering entered links.

[image]

Comment: forgot to emphasis that I use Drupal 6 and Drupal core's profile module not CCK profile .So there are no such options in my case

Comment: I have retagged your original question to let others know that you are using D6. Please try to be more specific when asking your questions. Many times, the Drupal version will dictate the answer. Maybe someone else can chime with a a solution in 6. My hunch that it will be an addition in your tpl file to achieve this in 6, but I am not completely sure (The core profile module in D6 was pretty limited).